# How to create Video Thumbnail from mp4 file which is in asset folder

Tags: android

I have a problem with creating Thumbnail from mp4 file which is in assets folder. Try to enter different asset`s path but no effect. How can I fix it?

That`s my piece of adapter code:

```
VideoEntry video = videos.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(video.getTitle());
    holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("file:///android_asset/videos/Core/Superman.mp4", Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND));
```

What is wrong?

**Solution:**

```
 AssetManager am = getAssets();
 InputStream ims = am.open("images/" + category + "/" + item.replace(" ", "_").replace(".mp4", ".png").toLowerCase());
 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
 holder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()` just queries an existing thumbnail from `MediaStore` or forces `MediaStore` to create it if it doesn't exist. This means that you can't create a thumbnail for a video file that isn't available for `MediaStore`, as it's an asset of your application and not an actual file on the SD card. You can extract your file to SD card or just provide a thumbnail created by yourself in another application. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me to not waste more time after hour of souliton searching. I have manage to set image by another way - > see in Solution:

Answer (score 1):

**This Worked For Me**

```
Bitmap getThumbnailOf(AssetFileDescriptor afd, int atTime) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = null;
    if (afd != null && afd.getFileDescriptor().valid()) try {
        retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            bitmap = retriever.getScaledFrameAtTime(atTime, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST, 1280, 720);
        } else {
            bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(atTime);
        }
        afd.close();
        retriever.release();
        Log.i("TAG", "getting bitmap process done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

**By Giving input as**

```
getThumbnailOf(getAssets().openFd("videos/Core/Superman.mp4"), 500000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assets it's app static resoureces' folder. You can create tumbnails for this video mannually and also put it to assets.

Comment: I did the same as you said. Thanks